# Cannot write multibyte string to Spanner properly from Dataflow Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I want to write multibyte string (e.g. japanese) to Spanner from Dataflow Pipeline. 
But it does not working.

Below is the code I tried.
(edited: I rewrote it that is closer to actual)

```
ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, Mutation>() {
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws IOException {
    TableRow row = c.element();
    Mutation.WriteBuilder mutationWriteBuilder = Mutation.newInsertOrUpdateBuilder('testtable');
    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : row.entrySet()) {
      String columnName = entry.getKey();
      Object value = entry.getValue();

      Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
      String str = new String(value.toString().getBytes(utf8), utf8);
      mutationWriteBuilder.set(columnName).to(str);
    }

    Mutation mutation = mutationWriteBuilder.build();
    c.output(mutation)
  }
}
```

This pipeline will succeed, but the value actually written is a garbled string like '�'.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmm, how are you reading the written value? Is it through the web console?

Comment: Yes. I read the value from the web console.

Comment: Hideyuki, sorry it turns out that you've hit a bug in the Dataflow write connector https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/5722

The pull request is merged and it should be fixed with 2.6.0 release, you can try using snapshot version of beam meanwhile.

Comment: Thanks Mairbek.

I tried using snapshot version of beam. But there was a problem with startup direct runner.
Concretely, I commented out dependency 'google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all' version 2.4.0 and add dependency 'beam-sdk-java-core', 'beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform', 'beam-runners-direct-java', 'beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java' version 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.
Is this dependency specification incorrect?

Comment: It should be correct, did you add the snaphshot repository?  

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </repository>

Comment: Yes. I did. Switching from 2.4.0 to 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT, it seems to give an error 'Project is not configured for Dataflow' in the Eclipse run configuration. And I cannot select Runner on the Pipeline Arguments tab.

Comment: This encoding bug also causes many other problems including random EOFException during large writes, and also corruption / failure to write any fields following one with the badly encoded data.  See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111823939

Comment: Did using the latest version, solved the issue?

Comment: @MonicaPC
Yes. This fixed by 2.7.0. refs: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4359